# htaccess timtumb issue for using subdomain url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, timthumb

I am newbie to htaccess. i am using timthumb for resizing the images

```
RewriteRule ^inner-banner/(.*)\.([jpg|gif|png|JPG|GIF|PNG]+)$ timthumb.php?src=http://mydomain.com/images/banner/$1.$2&h=350&w=960&zc=0 [QSA,L]
```

This gives me the result : http://mydomain.com/inner-banner/myimage.jpg

Now i mapped a subdomain to the folder images.

http:// subdomain.mydomain.com is mapped to the images folder. So now i need to show the above result as http:// subdomain.mydomain.com/inner-banner/myimage.jpg

i modified the htaccess like

```
RewriteRule ^inner-banner/(.*)\.([jpg|gif|png|JPG|GIF|PNG]+)$ timthumb.php?src=http://subdomain.mydomain.com/banner/$1.$2&h=350&w=960&zc=0 [QSA,L]
```

Expected Result: http://subdomain.mydomain.com/inner-banner/myimage.jpg

but it is not coming like that. it shows 404. Kindly help me resolving this issue.